# Concatenating two Pandas dataframes while keeping the values from the first one for repeated cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes:
[df1=](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8I7S.jpg)
and
[df2=](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC2IM.jpg)

I want to concatenate the two dataframes at all rows and columns while the output has unique rows for the first two columns 'parameter' and 'date' and unique columns for the other columns.

Recently I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76953850/merging-two-dataframes-at-only-different-rows-and-columns/76954021).
Giving a try to the accepted solution there, I see an extra row for the date '2023-01-01':

code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'parameter' : ['A', 'B'], 'date' : ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'], 'column2' : ['A2_1', 'B2_2'], 'column3' : ['A3_1', 'B3_2'], 'column4' : ['A4_1', 'B4_2'], 'column5' : ['A5_1', 'B5_2'] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'parameter' : ['A', 'C'], 'date' : ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-03'], 'column4' : ['A4_1_1', 'C4_3'], 'column5' : ['A5_1_1', 'C5_3'], 'column6' : ['A6_2', 'C6_3'], 'column7' : ['A7_2', 'C7_3'] })
res = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(['parameter', 'date']).fillna('').reset_index(drop=True)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
  parameter        date column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7
0         A  2023-01-01    A2_1    A3_1    A4_1    A5_1                
1         A  2023-01-01                  A4_1_1  A5_1_1    A6_2    A7_2
2         B  2023-01-02    B2_2    B3_2    B4_2    B5_2                
3         C  2023-01-03                    C4_3    C5_3    C6_3    C7_3
```

But I expect to get the following dataframe as the resulting output:

[df_result=](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MjUo.jpg)

Please note that for the repeated cells, the value of the first dataframe should be kept.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the above output dataframe preferably without using loops and conditions?

Comment: I believe the `drop_duplicates` method has an option to only keep the first and to compare duplicates by certain columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try grouping them by the parameter and date and taking the first non-null value from each group.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values(by=['parameter','date']).groupby(['parameter','date']).first().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! This solution worked for the problem.